# How do I change user.timezone in system properties when jenkins is run as war?

Tags: jenkins

If jenkins is installed as a package manager, user.timezone can be modified by editing the jenkins file in the /etc/default/ path.

However, when running jenkins as war, there is no file in the path, so it cannot be set.

Is there a file or method to modify the system properties of jenkins when it is run as war?

Comment: I found anwser.
Just type 
System.setProperty('org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone', 'America/New_York')
 in the jenkins script console.
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/change-system-timezone/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the timezone as the system property `user.timezone` when starting the war file like `java -Duser.timezone=America/Chicago -jar jenkins.war`. You can verify that the timezone has been set correctly by going to the `jenkins_host/systemInfo` page